# Binary format of memory address. Computer organization

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm having a bit of an issue understanding what is going on here, and can't seem to wrap my head about it.

Notes:
[Course notes about topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hxis.jpg)

Example:

```
Memory location 0x1f6
What is the binary format of this address? 1 1111 0110
What are tag, block index, and block offset? 3, 7, 6
```

My own work:

```
Memory location 0x033
What is the binary format of this address? 0 0011 0011
What are tag, block index, and block offset? 0 6, 3

Memory location 0x009
What is the binary format of this address? 0 0000 1001
What are tag, block index, and block offset? 0, 1, 1

Memory location 0x652
What is the binary format of this address? 0110 0101 0010
What are tag, block index, and block offset? 12, 10, 2
```

These are my attempts, but I have not a clue if I'm doing it right, and I have a feeling that I am not, as least for the last one, which I believe is wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The answer is very dependent on the interpretation of the bits, which is something that your homework or classwork defined. There is no general definition for decoding memory addresses.

Comment: @nneonneo I have attached the only portion of notes we were given on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. The block offset is dependent upon the block size, in this case 16bytes, so it requires 4 binary digits to represent it. Next, the block index is dependent upon the number of blocks, in this case 8 (0-7), which requires 3 binary digits. Finally, the tag is made up of the remaining binary digits after you convert the hex memory location to binary.

Example

```
Memory location 0x652
What is the binary format of this address? 0110 0101 0010
What is the binary representation of tag, block index, and block offset? 1100 101 0010
What are tag, block index, and block offset? 12, 7, 2
```